# Help with a nested query !

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

```
        int id = 1;
        string chain = "(";
        SqlDataReader dr = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(string.Format("SELECT a.Id as x, c.Id as y From Friends b INNER JOIN Users a ON b.SenderId = a.Id INNER JOIN Users c ON b.ReceiverId = c.Id WHERE (c.Id = {0} OR a.Id = {0}) AND State = '{1}'", id, "ok"));
        if (dr.HasRows)
            while (dr.Read())
                if (id == int.Parse(dr["y"].ToString()))
                    chain += dr["x"].ToString() + ", ";
                else
                    chain += dr["y"].ToString() + ", ";
        if (chain.Length > 1)
            chain = chain.Substring(0, chain.Length - 2) + ")";
        else
            chain = "(0)";
        // Chain has for example  => (2, 3, 4, 5) => which are the Ids for Users's Friends 
        string str = "SELECT TOP 20 a.*, b.UserName as Sender, c.UserName as Receiver, b.Avatar as SenderPic";
        str += " FROM Events a INNER JOIN Users b ON a.SenderId = b.Id INNER JOIN Users c ON a.ReceiverId = c.Id ";
        str += "WHERE SenderId IN ";
        str += chain;
        str += " OR ReceiverId IN";
        str += chain;
        str += " Order BY Id desc";
        dr = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(str);
```

`chain` considered as the user's friends .
does any one know how to execute this query with JOINS  !?  Thanks a lot ..

Comment: I think you should remove the C# code and rephrase the question to be about the SQL involved. Include some more info about the schema. This will probably get you more answers.

Comment: It's very hard to figure out what you are really interested in. The code sample posted is very messy and hard to make sense of. If you want to know how to turn a SQL query with `WHERE SenderId IN (....)` into a query with JOINs, then please give us just that SQL query to look at - not the C# code producing it....... you make it unnecessarily difficult and hard on folks to answer you.....

Comment: Is it intended that a "ReceiverId" matched in the first query should be eligible for matching a "SenderId" in the second?

Comment: Simply I want to get user's event from Table "Events" according to his friends .. for instance if user 1 has 20 friends I should take the events for all of them . but the big problem is that I don't know if the friend Id saved as SenderId or a ReceiverId in table Events , so I build the first query to get the user' friends to use it in the second with the CLAUSE IN => where senderId IN (User's Friends) OR RecieverID IN (User's Friends) .. ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct TOP(20) e.*, u1.UserName As Sender,
u2.UserName As Receiver, u1.Avatar AS SenderPic  
FROM Friends f INNER JOIN Users u 
ON(u.Id = f.SenderId OR u.Id = f.ReceiverId) AND State = 'ok' 
INNER JOIN Events e 
ON(f.SenderId = e.SenderId OR f.SenderId = e.ReceiverId 
OR f.ReceiverId = e.SenderId OR f.ReceiverId = e.ReceiverId) 
INNER JOIN Users u1 
ON (e.SenderId = u1.Id) 
INNER JOIN Users u2 
ON (e.ReceiverId = u2.Id) 
WHERE u.Id = @id;
```

Answer (score 2):

First, try to get rid of pushing parameter values with `string.Format` into SQL queries. That's a huge security issue.

To your query. I have to admit, I'm a bit lost in your string concatenation :-P, but if I'm right, you want to get the Events and some user information. As far as I can see, SenderId and ReciverId are already your ids. If so, you can completely remove the first SELECT and provide **id** (as parameter) directly into your second SQL statement like this (only the SQL):

**Edit:** Tom showed me the missing part (Status=Ok)

<del>SELECT TOP(20)
       a.*
       ,b.UserName as Sender
       ,c.UserName as Receiver
       ,b.Avatar as SenderPic
    FROM Events a 
       INNER JOIN Users b ON a.SenderId = b.Id 
       INNER JOIN Users c ON a.ReceiverId = c.Id 
    WHERE
       a.SenderId = @id
       OR a.ReceiverId = @id;</del>

Corrected version:

```
; WITH OkUsers AS (
   SELECT
      u.*
   FROM Users u
      JOIN Friends f ON u.Id = f.SenderId OR u.Id = f.RecipientId
   WHERE
      f.Status = 'Ok'
)
SELECT TOP(20)
   a.*
   ,b.UserName as Sender
   ,c.UserName as Receiver
   ,b.Avatar as SenderPic
FROM Events a 
   INNER JOIN OkUsers b ON a.SenderId = b.Id 
   INNER JOIN OkUsers c ON a.ReceiverId = c.Id 
WHERE
   a.SenderId = @id
   OR a.ReceiverId = @id;
```

Comment: +1 absolutely - concatenating together a SQL command like that is a HUGE GAPING SQL injection hole waiting to be exploited!

Comment: I think the original had an extra WHERE clause on Friends.State = 'ok' (assuming the state column is defined on the friends table)

Comment: @Tom Carver Thanks for the hint. I updated the SQL statement.

Comment: I don't have a specific Id to use it in WHERE SenderId = @id OR  ReceiverId = @id , instead I have a user Id which I can use it to Get his friends from table "Friends" so I has used "IN" .. ANY Suggestions !?!

Comment: You don't need the IN if you work with a single statement (what was your question). Use a DbParameter to provide the @id value from your "id" variable.

Comment: Florian Reischl Can you give me your msn if you have one !?!?

Comment: @Rawhi I don't have one and I don't think this would be a good solution. First, my humpy knowledge would never worth a community with more than 100,000 users, so your solution probably wouldn't be the best. Second, the great thing about communities like this is, the solution for one problem can help many others who find it, here. Anything we would do in a _private_ area would be lost for all the others.

Answer (score 0):

I think that might help:

```
--step[1]
SELECT DISTINCT CASE
WHEN a.Id = 1 THEN c.ID
WHEN c.Id = 1 THEN a.Id
ELSE
0 
END AS ID
INTO #OkUsers
From Friends b INNER JOIN Users a 
ON b.SenderId = a.Id INNER JOIN Users c 
ON b.ReceiverId = c.Id 
WHERE (c.Id = @id OR a.Id = @id) AND State = 'Ok';

--step[2]
SELECT TOP 20 a.*, b.UserName as Sender, c.UserName as Receiver, b.Avatar as SenderPic
FROM Events a INNER JOIN Users b ON a.SenderId = b.Id INNER JOIN Users c ON a.ReceiverId = c.Id
INNER JOIN #OkUsers ON #OkUsers.ID = SenderId OR #OkUsers.ID = ReceiverId
EXCEPT
SELECT TOP 20 a.*, b.UserName as Sender, c.UserName as Receiver, b.Avatar as SenderPic
FROM Events a INNER JOIN Users b ON a.SenderId = b.Id INNER JOIN Users c ON a.ReceiverId = c.Id
--INNER JOIN #OkUsers ON #OkUsers.ID = SenderId OR #OkUsers.ID = ReceiverId
WHERE SenderId IN (SELECT ID FROM #OkUsers) 
    OR ReceiverId IN(SELECT ID FROM #OkUsers);

DROP TABLE #OkUsers;
```

Temp tables work good with very large volume of data.Otherwise you can use a memory table.

Comment: how can I use this in my code !
Also , I've extracted all the identification numbers to all the friends of a member and then put it in a variable of type String to be used with IN Clause in the Second query .. is that a good way or what !?

Comment: any sql code that gives you the final result in only one trip to the db is better than doing it with two round trips. Also getting the data from sql server into memory and working with it is better performance than doing it all with sql server, but this is not an always-valid rule because it depends on the volume of data, the application server capacity and the users load...etc

Comment: I can't even think how this could be written in a one single sql statement !!! #OkUsers => SELECT => DROP

Comment: you can create a stored procedure and put this code inside it and call the procedure from within your C# code.